# Identificar instancias do skype usando biblioteca SKYPE4COM.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, skype

Estou trabalhando em um projeto `C#` `WindowsForms` e utilizando a biblioteca `SKYPE4COM.dll`.

Fiz uma aplicação que busca uma instancia do skype rodando, o problema é que ao atribuir a instancia conforme código abaixo ele pega a primeira que logou, sendo que uso 3 skypes no meu computador. Eu gostaria de buscar pelo nome do skype.

**Existe alguma forma de realizar a identificação do usuário atual logado no skype usando esta biblioteca ?**

Caso não seja possível fazer a identificação do usuário pela biblioteca `SKYPE4COM.dll` existe  alguma outra maneira de fazer isso ?

**Código** :

```
private Skype skypeId;
 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    skypeId = new Skype();
}
```